# How to enable features for php-curl

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, kerberos, spnego

I need my CLI PHP script to post some value to a SPNEGO authenticated site.

```
$ch = curl_init(USERSPACE_MYSQL_SERVICES);

curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => ??, //Set to SPNEGO
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [...] 
]);
```

However SPNEGO is disabled for some reason:

Extract from my phpinfo:

```
curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.21.6
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => Yes
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
Largefile => Yes
NTLM => Yes
SPNEGO => No <---------------
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
krb4 => No
libz => Yes
CharConv => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.0e
ZLib Version => 1.2.3.4
```

The Apache server that it is communicating to is set up as follows:

```
            AuthType Kerberos
            AuthName "Kerberos LAN Realm Login"
            KrbAuthRealm LAN
            Krb5KeyTab /etc/apache2/auth/apache2.keytab

            KrbMethodK5Passwd Off
            KrbSaveCredentials On
            KrbLocalUserMapping On
```

When trying it through the command line `curl` it works, but I have to input a dummy password:

```
curl --negotiate -u user https://example.com
Enter host password for user 'user':
<html>
...
```

How can I enable SPNEGO for the php curl and how would I use it in my script?

### Update

I have tried the following:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_ANY,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [...]
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

if ($info['http_code'] >= 400)
      die("HTTP ERROR {$info['http_code']}");

echo $response;
```

And I get: `HTTP ERROR 401`

Comment: [SPNEGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPNEGO) is not a type of authentication, it is a mechanism that clients and servers use to determine what sort of auth types the other supports. Your server actually uses Kerberos as an auth method, which AFAIK should work with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY)` (although the `krb4 => No` indicates this may not work on your box). The options displayed by `phpinfo()` are build-time options, you would need to rebuild the extension in order to change them.

Comment: @DaveRandom, ok i'll try that, thank you. I have been looking for the build time options, but couldn't find them. Also, my server is krb5 and not krb4.

Comment: @DaveRandom I have tried with `CURL_AUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE` and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may need to recompile curl with the argument "--with-spnego" in your configure command.

For an example of a configure command:
http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2012-02/0094.html

Full on docs (overkill):
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html

Comment: Hey thanks, but that doesn't seem to be for phps CURL. So if the features are read from the same lib that the cli tool uses, I may not need SPNEGO enabled then?

Comment: Anyway I figured how to do my thing without SPNEGO. I will post most answer now and accept yours as you have directly answered my question.

Comment: How to recompile `php_curl.dll` on Windows server with `krb4 -> yes`?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I do not need SPNEGO enabled with CURL as it works fine with GSS auth. Just like with the CLI I need to set `CURLOPT_USERPWD` without providing a password:

```
$username = rtrim(`id -un`, "\n");
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_ANY,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [...],
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$username:"
]);
```

Now it works just fine.